# How to handle effortless questions in the review area?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

There are tons of questions where the OP clearly hasn't put any effort into solving themselves, like https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6017821 where there's no attempt at any code.

How should we treat these questions? Should we close them? If yes, what reason fits best?

Comment: Close for being "too broad" ... I guess. OP needs to provide more details as what has been tried, any prior research results, etc.

Comment: How do you manage this kind of question ? I feel that `unclear what you're asking` might also be appropriate. Thanks

Comment: [That answer is great for defining such problems.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/173052)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there is no effort from the OP you can either close vote as Unclear or too broad.

The Unclear reason fits because we have no solid ground to build our answer on. We have to assume/imagine all kind of things on behalf of the OP. Because of the unclear nature it is not only unclear for the OP but also for future visitors of that question. Those that are interested in answers for the question need to be able to determine if the situation of the OP matches theirs.

The too broad reason fits if an answer needs to cover a lot of ground to come close to a decent answer. Basically those OP's are better helped if they get a training or read a good introduction book.

Your close flag/vote can be accompanied by a down vote if it is apparent that the OP didn't bother to do any research themselves but instead used the Stack Overflow *Ask Question* button as their first (and only) option.

Comment: The Q&A helped me decide how to vote on a question today since I wasn't exactly sure as to how to handle it, seeing there was code in the question, yet just to merely ask "how to put this" in their code. Personally, I thought it was pretty trivial.